# Trying to setup LAMPy

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am new to using (ubuntu) Linux as a platform for web design, and am currently attempting to install LAMP to allow me to view my work locally. I have everything installed - however I am running into a few problems and do not know what route to take since I am newish to linux as well.

I am trying to access phpMyAdmin via http://localhost which is where the first of my problems popped up. I don't know what the login and password should be - I didn't setup anything like that during the installation of the LAMP server. After testing a few different probable account/password combinations i see that it gives me an error message saying "#1045 can't log in to the MySQL server"

So, I opened terminal to see if mysql was running, and I get error 1045 (28000) access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (bla bla bla)

Comment: Default is root with no password. If a password is set,  you would have created one when you installed MySQL as part of the LAMP stack. To reset it, read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Answer (score 0):

You should try username `root` and no password.
By default MySQL is installed with username root and blank password

The Password is set to `password` in some versions.

If still you are not able to login then please share your installation procedure for LAMP stack.

Comment: I have to disagree with Bono, I think this looks like a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: I have to agree, it was reasonable - he was just trying to help me trouble shoot the issue further. 
And to answer his question - I followed word for word the directions from: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu. When this was unsuccessful, I back-tracked the install then I searched further finding https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP and following this word for word only to receive the same result. I am truly stumped on this.